# Deleting unmodified files after they have been copied into a folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

as you can see the following code will extract all the files in my "CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone" folder, and it will place all of them in my "FilesExtracted" folder.  My question is after all the files have been placed into the "FilesExtracted" folder, how can I delete all files that have not been modified recently.  I would like to only keep the files that have been modified in past few months, or the last year either one would be great to figure out. Thanks :)

Imports System.IO

Public Class frmExtractionator

```
Dim txtFiles1 As Control

Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

    Dim sourceDirectory As String = "E:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone"
    Dim archiveDirectory As String = "E:\FilesExtracted"

    Try
        Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory)

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(archiveDirectory)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveDirectory)
        End If

        For Each currentFile As String In txtFiles
            Dim fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)
            File.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))
        Next
    Catch eT As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2fzb02.aspx) class and the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class to get information on various time properties connected to the file

```
Try
    Dim di As DirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory)
    Dim fi as FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    .....

    For Each currentFile As FileInfo In fi
        File.Move(currentFile.FullName, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, currentFile.Name))

        Dim dt As DateTime = currentFile.LastWriteTime
        ' Add 3 months to the last write and check if it is less than today '
        if dt.AddMonths(3) < DateTime.Today then 
            File.Delete(currentFile.FullName)
        End If
    Next
Catch eT As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
End Try
```